# bootstrap modal close after 4 seconds or user click

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

How would I set a timeout for a bootstrap modal? After getting the ajax data back that the message returned by php contains the term `success`, I want to give the user the option to close the window. However, I also just want to have a 4 second count down. Currently the second the success message comes back the modal hides itself.

```
$('#forgotform').submit(function (e) {
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#forgotsubmit').button('loading');
    var post = $('#forgotform').serialize();
    var action = $('#forgotform').attr('action');
    $("#message").slideUp(350, function () {
        $('#message').hide();
        $.post(action, post, function (data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#usernamemail').focus();
            if (data.match('success') !== null) {
                $('#forgotform').slideUp('slow');
                $('#forgotsubmit').button('complete');
                $('#forgotsubmit').click(function (eb) {
                    eb.preventDefault();
                    $('#forgot-form').modal('hide');
                });
                setTimeout($('#forgot-form').modal('hide'), 10000);
            } else {
                $('#forgotsubmit').button('reset');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens when you comment out the `setTimeout`? Does it automatically closes itself?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When calling setTimeout(), wrap your command in an anonymous function. Otherwise the command will be executed immediately.

```
setTimeout(function() {$('#forgot-form').modal('hide');}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 21):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#Modal').modal('hide')
}, 4000);
```

//where modal's id is 'Modal'

Answer (score 1):

The following code is used for hiding the model on an `onClick` event. Use the classname for the `onClick` listener and the modal id as the selector to hide.

```
$('.class_name').on('click',function(){
    $('#modal_id').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Hi there. I think this wasn't quite the correct answer for what was asked

Comment: Hi @eykhagen Alex also want user click and hide modal.

Comment: You left out the time

Comment: @ebentil You read my note above it's only for `onclick` event.

Comment: This actually a wrong answer but  %100 I need this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit1').click(function(){
        setTimeout("$('#myModal').modal('hide');",3000);
    });
```

this is working for popup delaying 3 seconds in closing.
please check with the `$('#submit1')` for this click I have written the code.

Comment: Your answer does not bring anything new to the problem, which was solved 4 years ago.