# How can I close bootstrap modal after open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project and I'm using bootstrap modal and my modal must open automatically it's okey so far then open I want to close it after 10 or 30 seconds how to do it ?

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(e){
    var delayModal = $(e).parents(".modal").attr("data-delay");
     $('#memberModal').modal('show');
  }, parseInt(delayModal)*1000);

});
```

but it works with this function but this is not dynamically could you help me to do what I want ? and auto closing with settimeout ? I gotta learn how to do it

```js
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(e){
     $('#memberModal').modal('show');
  }, parseInt(5)*1000);
 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="modal fade" id="memberModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-delay="5">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Thank you for signing in!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>However the account provided is not known.
          <BR> If you just got invited to the group, please wait for a day to have the database synchronized.</p>

        <p>You will now be shown the Demo site.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you satisfied by previous answer? I have another idea how to start count after modal show

Comment: I want to do autocamitcally and I wonder your idea

Comment: Did you try the answers from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730284/bootstrap-modal-close-after-4-seconds-or-user-click

Comment: I know how to do it but I didn't know how will I apply after open my modal with settimeout because I guess multiple settimeout to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `$('#memberModal').modal('hide')` in the timeout, after you open the modal.

```js
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(e){
    $('#memberModal').modal('show');
  }, parseInt($('#memberModal').attr('data-open')) * 1000);
  setTimeout(function(e){
    $('#memberModal').modal('hide');
  }, parseInt($('#memberModal').attr('data-delay')) * 1000);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="modal fade" id="memberModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-delay="6" data-open="2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Thank you for signing in!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>However the account provided is not known.
          <BR> If you just got invited to the group, please wait for a day to have the database synchronized.</p>

        <p>You will now be shown the Demo site.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you it's great but is there any way to do it automatically ? for example I have `data-delay` attribute top of the html code and if `data-delay` 5 seconds than open after 5 seconds and I have `data-close` and if it's 10 seconds than close after 10 seconds ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to now read the `data-delay` attribute.

Comment: no I mean on my html I will add `data-xxx` attribute and if my value 5 than open after 5 seconds and I will add `data-close` attribute and if my value 10 and close after 10 seconds..sorry about my english

Comment: I added `data-open`, so it will now delay both actions. Is that correct?

Comment: yes exactly and you got learn to me how use two multiple with js thank you so much and sorry about my bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it dynamically like this

```js
$(function(){
var delayModal = $(".modal").attr("data-delay");
  setTimeout(function(e){
     $('#memberModal').modal('show');
  }, parseInt(delayModal)*1000);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="modal fade" id="memberModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-delay="5">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Thank you for signing in!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>However the account provided is not known.
          <BR> If you just got invited to the group, please wait for a day to have the database synchronized.</p>

        <p>You will now be shown the Demo site.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it was the answer that I looking for thank you so much and I have another question too.. I want to close it after open with attribute like data-delay

Answer (score 1):

Automation show and hide modal

```js
$(function(){
 var modal = $('#memberModal');
 var showDelay = parseInt(modal.data('delay'));
 var closeDelay = parseInt(modal.data('close'));
 var openByTimeout = false;
    setTimeout(function(e){
        openByTimeout = true;
        modal.modal('show');
    }, showDelay*1000);
    modal.on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        if (openByTimeout) {
            setTimeout(function(e){
                openByTimeout = false;
                modal.modal('hide');
            }, closeDelay*1000);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal fade" id="memberModal" data-delay="1" data-close="2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Thank you for signing in!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>However the account provided is not known.
          <BR> If you just got invited to the group, please wait for a day to have the database synchronized.</p>

        <p>You will now be shown the Demo site.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```