# Close Bootstrap modal on the delay using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I try to:

- Show modal
- Wait 3 seconds
- Hide modal

Why it doesn't work?

My code:

```js
var $modal = $("#exampleModal");

$modal
  .modal("show")
  .delay(3000)
  .modal("hide")
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I am aware of [an answer to the "bootstrap modal close after 4 seconds or user click"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740669/6439240) question but I want pure jQuery solution for my code to be more consistent.

---

**UDPATE:** I specifically want to use the jQuery `.delay()` method.

Comment: You're not understanding how jQuery `.delay` works. It only works with the jQuery effects queues, so it's perfect for slides and fades, etc but not delaying something like `setTimeout` delays something. It is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use javascript function `setTimeout()` to execute the hide with a predefined delay like you want.

**NOTE:** I'm not sure if you're aware how jQuery `.delay` works. It only works with the jQuery effects queues, so it's perfect for slides and fades, etc but not delaying something like `setTimeout` delays something.

It is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function.

```
var $modalDialog = $("#exampleModal");
$modalDialog.modal('show');

setTimeout(function() {
  $modalDialog.modal('hide');
}, 3000);
```

If you really wanted something with `delay` you could look at using Underscore's `_.delay()` function:

```
var log = _.bind(console.log, console);
_.delay(log, 1000, 'logged later');
=> 'logged later' // Appears after one second.
```

> Much like `setTimeout`, invokes function after wait milliseconds. If you pass the optional arguments, they will be forwarded on to the function when it is invoked.

http://underscorejs.org/#delay

Comment: how to do without jquery , is there something like data-dismis-delay attribute ?